# Implement pandas groupby using numpy vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to group my pandas dataframe and perform some aggregations but on scaling it performs badly. With dataframe size of 3M it takes approx 3hrs to process.
Can you suggest me how I can implement it using numpy vectorization or any other faster way of doing same.

```
signature_df = (
            df.groupby("signature")
                .agg({"inputTables": "sum", "outputTables": "sum", "id": lambda x: list(x)})
                .reset_index()
        )
```

Comment: hard to know without a reproducible example. Aggregating as list is probably not a good idea though.

Comment: Can you suggest how can I use numpy vectorization here

Comment: Not without a reproducible example

Comment: signature dtype is Object, inputTables and outputTables are int64. Let's skip id for now

Comment: `groupby` isn't slow, but the `agg` actions can vary widely in speed. Your solution, if any is in the pandas docs, not some poorly imagined 'numpy vectorization'.